# How do I request currently unavailable options to be sold?

Tags: options

How can I request options:

1. for a certain stock that currently has no options traded?
2. at a more extreme Strike Price? E.g. if I fancy buying OTM options?
3. with a farther expiration?
4. Does the CBOE have a specific email or online form for requesting options?

Answer (score 1):

Are the other answers here correct? I called CBOE, and staff answered just like [the following](https://twitter.com/pateltexas/status/1291847768215040002/photo/1).

[image]

Comment: I'm impressed that they use Jira for this. :) As I already mentioned, their web form says they only accept such suggestions from TBHs. You should ask your broker (assuming you use a broker you can talk to) to submit this request, or find someone else who's a TBH.

Answer (score 0):

1. Contact the CBOE or have your broker do it.  They will list options if there is sufficient interest.  Sufficient interest can often be one trade.
2. Same as #1.  Also, you can trade these deep OTM options OTC.
3. If the expiry is longer than the LEAPs, they will most likely have to be done OTC.

Comment: Have your dealer contact them.  They will be more receptive to their customers requests.  They usually have a salesperson assigned to the account.  At least I did when I was a market maker.

Comment: @NNOXApps  Yeah, in general people only listen to their customers.  Also, they won't list something unless there is a trade (in addition to all their other requirements re: liquidity and such).

Answer (score 0):

1 according to http://www.cboe.com/education/getting-started/quick-facts/options-marketplace

> Are there requirements for individual stock issues to underlie
> exchange-listed equity options?
>
> Yes, option exchanges have certain eligibility requirements for stocks
> to become "optionable." Among the criteria are share price, number of
> shares outstanding, average daily volume, and "distribution" (i.e.
> shares outstanding owned by a minimum number of investors). The NYSE
> and NASDAQ also have their own listing requirements. Although Cboe has
> staff that is constantly reviewing stocks that are candidates for
> listing, it is possible that a stock has been overlooked. *If you feel
> this might be the case, you can contact the Cboe and suggest it.*

It sure sounds like they welcome suggestions, but there's a good chance that if they don't have options now, then it may not meet some eligibility requirements.

They even have a way on their web site https://www.cboe.com/aboutcboe/ContactCBOEEmail.aspx?Topic=New+Option+Listing+Requests to contact them to suggest new options. (However it seems that you either need to be a ["cboe trading permit holder"](http://www.cboe.com/publish/CFETradingPermitForms/TPHPermitProgram.pdf) or ask your broker to make the suggestions)

1,2,3 - you might have better luck talking to some bank's equities desk about OTC trades.

Comment: yes, they have a web form for that, I just edited & added the address to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Option exchanges are  not going to offer options on a stock just because you want them.  They have specific listing requirements that must be met in order for options to be offered.

One of my stocks has   weekly options from 10/09 through 11/13 that trade in 50 cent increments but the 11/20 monthly expiration only offers 2-1/2 point increments.  I e-mailed the CBOE earlier today requesting that they add at least 1 point increments.  You can e-mail them from their web site.  They tend to add strikes if they are reasonable requests.

Comment: Hi again Bob! Please see my answer.